# ArrayList.remove(Object) throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an observable, that notifies all of its registered observers.

```
public void notifyObservers(T message) {
      notifying = true;
      for (Observer<T> observer : observers)
         observer.notify(message);
      notifying= false;
   }
```

I also have this method in my observable class:

```
public void removeObserver(final Observer<T> observer){
  if (!this.observers.contains(observer))
     return;

  if (!notifying) {
     this.observers.remove(observer);
     return;
  }

  final ArrayList<Observer<T>> observerList = this.observers;
  new Thread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
        while (notifying);
        observerList.remove(observer);
     }
  }).start();

}
```

To make shure that the remove calls are not made during the notifying, i wait in an new Thread for the notifying to be finished. However, one of the added Observers is calling the `removeObserver`-method of the observable it is added to in its `notify`-method and I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the line of the removecall of the ArrayList:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.fastRemove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at allgemeines.Observable$2.run(Observable.java:96)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why could that happen?

Comment: Please post the entire Exception and fix this line ('for (Observer<T> observer : observer)'). This does not seem right. A mcve would also be helpful

Comment: Oh sorry you're right! I don't know what a mcve is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Well, I could'nt figure out why the Exception was thrown in my example in the question above, but I found a way to rewrite the method that worked. I converted the list into an array and iterated over that array instead of the list, which is an attribute:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public synchronized void notifyObservers(T message) {
    Object[] observerArray = observers.toArray();
    for (Object observer : observerArray)
        ((Observer<T>) observer).notify(message);
}
```

The `add` and `remove` methods are now very simple (just delegating the method call to the `ArrayList`-methods:

```
public void addObserver(Observer<T> observer){
    this.observers.add(observer);
}

public void removeObserver(Observer<T> observer) {
    this.observers.remove(observer);
}
```

Would be still interesting to know why my first solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the notifying boolean, why not use locking with synchronized? Something like:

```
public void notifyObservers(T message) {
  synchronized(observers) {
    for (Observer<T> observer : observers)
       observer.notify(message);
  }
```

...

```
public void removeObserver(final Observer<T> observer){
   synchronized(this.observers) { 

     final ArrayList<Observer<T>> observerList = this.observers;

     observerList.remove(observer);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that technique. Does that mean that the locked variable cannot be touched by other threads?

Comment: When I do it like that I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException at the remove call.

Comment: David, Yes, you can lock an object with synchronized which allows you to make thread-safe classes, but it must be the same object. Are these methods in the same class? It wasn't 100% clear to me. Also do you still have the first remove call? I wasn't clear on why you had two.

Comment: And if you are getting the concurrent modification, you aren't locking it up tight. Just make sure you don't access it anywhere but within a synchronized block and you should be set.

Comment: First I told you wrong about the ConcurrentModificationException, sorry. It isn't thrown at the remove call, but in the foreach-loop inside the ArrayList class. These two methods are in the same class. The locked object is definetely always the same ArrayList. It's a final attribute of my Observable class.

Comment: The removeObserver-method isn't called in a different thread. It is called in the same thread. So it's not enough to lock the ArrayList from other threads. It needs to be locked for every thread during the foreach-loop. Because of that I used the boolean, but it didn't work.

Comment: David, it's unclear to me why you would need a separate thread at this point from the code you've shown to remove from the list. You should have your array list (your one and only array list) accessible only via external methods to your class, which it seems as if you do. In that class, if you use a synchronized(list) approach, no matter who calls your methods, you lock the list and remove from it or notify members as needed.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the synchronised(list) lock doesn't work in the same thread. It just locks objects from other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't thread safe.
try to lock your observers by synchronized in the remove and notify methods.

Comment: The removeObserver-method isn't called in a different thread. It is called in the same thread by one of the observers. The ArrayList needs somehow to be locked for all threads. Because of that I used the boolean, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to remove from the bottom up, that way you shouldn't be out of bounds. Don't know if this will help with your particular problem though.

```
for (int i = list.Count-1; i>-1; i--)
{
    list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: That would probably avoid an Exception, but it wouldn't prevent the adding and removing of elements of the ArrayList during the loop. This solution would in some cases lead to not reaching every element of the list or apply some objects twice if some are removed or added during the loop.